# why std::distance struck in a stl map?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use std::distance to find the index of my element.

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> m = {{1, "huang"}, {2, "wei"}, {3, "pu"}};
  auto it = m.find(2);
  cout << std::distance(it, m.begin()) << endl; // struck here
  cout << std::distance(it, m.end()) << endl;
}
```

but i found the code is struck in `cout`, what's the problem with my code?

Comment: That should probably be `std::distance(m.begin(), it)` .

Comment: *The behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first.* [distance ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: If the compiler doesn't deduce that the behavior is undefined, and instead codes to try and increment `it` until it reaches `m.begin()` it will take a long time. Or it will take a short time but the fans may speed up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trouble comes from the fact that `std::distance(first, last)`...

> Returns the number of hops from first to last - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

So you need to change to this:

```
// ...   
std::distance(m.begin(), it); // the number of hops from m.begin() to it
// ...
```

Note, that this way we present `distance` with a valid **iterator range**. There are requirements on iterators forming an iterator range:

- They have to refer to elements (or one past the last element) of the
  same container
- It is possible to reach `end` by repeatedly incrementing `begin`. In
  other words, `end` must not precede `begin`.

*Where the second requirement was violated in your case.*

Answer (score 5):

Iterator of `std::map` is not random access, then for [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance),

> If InputIt is not LegacyRandomAccessIterator, the behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first.

So the behavior of `std::distance(it, m.begin())` is undefined, `m.begin()` (pointing to the 1st element) is not reachable by incrementing `it` (pointing to the 2nd element). You should use `std::distance(m.begin(), it)` instead.